# How to refactor this in J?

Tags: refactoring, j, tacit-programming

My newbie solution to Project Euler #1

```
+/((0=3|1+i.1000-1) +. (0=5|1+i.1000-1)) * (1+i.1000-1)
```

I know that this can be refactored, and transformed into a function, i don't know how to do it, and I would have to read all the labs to learn it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't necessary to "handle zero" because adding zero won't change the answer so you can just use `i.` to generate your list of numbers below 1000, for example:

```
   i. 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

J works best with arrays so you should be able to ask for the residue (`|`) of 3 and 5 at the same time, you can use rank (`"`) to control how the arguments are fed to residue:

```
   3 5 |"0 1 i. 10
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
```

The `|"0 1` says to feed the left argument to `|` an-item-at-a-time while feeding the right arguments a-line-at-a-time. Because the right argument only consists of one line, it is fed repeatedly to each of the left argument items.

Now we can do the `0=` to the whole array:

```
   0 = 3 5 |"0 1 i. 10
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Insert an OR condition between the two items (lines) of the array:

```
  +./ 0 = 3 5 |"0 1 i. 10
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

Get the index of each 1 in the list/vector:

```
  I. +./ 0 = 3 5 |"0 1 i. 10
0 3 5 6 9
```

And sum:

```
 +/ I. +./ 0 = 3 5 |"0 1 i. 10
```

23

You can make this an explicit function/verb fairly easily:

```
   euler1=: verb define
+/ I. +./ 0 = 3 5 |"0 1 i. y
)
```

Or once you get the hang of tacit J you could define:

```
   euler1=: +/@I.@(+./)@(0 = 3 5 |"0 1 i.)
```

Comment: The only thing I would add to this clear answer is that `|"0 1` could be written as `|/` (modulus table).  The table adverb `/` can clarify some algorithms where the core function is scalar (i.e. rank 0).

Answer (score 1):

- Refactor `0=` (will increases the program size)

```
+/((3|1+i.1000-1)+.&(0=])5|1+i.1000-1)*1+i.1000-1
```

- Refactor `1+i.1000-1`

```
+/(((3|])+.&(0=[)5|])1+i.1000-1)*1+i.1000-1
```

- Refactor `1+i.1000-1` again

```
+/(*(3|])+.&(0=[)5|])1+i.1000-1
```

The only thing I couldn't refactor so far is the `|` operator